# Is there an equivalent to jQuery Masonry for MooTools?

Tags: jquery, mootools, jquery-masonry

I need a MooTools plugin that accomplishes the same thing as: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Does one exist?

Comment: [Use Google](http://www.google.com/webhp?q=mootools%20masonry), not SO, for these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this 
[mooMasonry](https://github.com/orefalo/mooMasonry)

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how I missed that. 2nd result on Google...

Comment: lol , it's ok some times all you need is an extra pair of eyes . and just for you not to miss a lot dont forget to mark the answer ;)

Comment: I did mark the answer... marking it again. Thanks again :)